# Oracle SUM with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm have a request over some imports, where I have a contract with multiple tranches at different costs over different periods of times. For example, you ask for a leasing for a total amount of 100k divided in 24 months paying for the first 10 months 3250€ and for the remaining 14 months you pay 5625€.

I have to calculate an Annual cost of the payments. This means that the first year I have paid 3250 * 10 + 5625 * 2 (the remaining 2 months to close the year). How do I do it in SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( CODCTR VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
                  FROMMONTH NUMBER(5), 
                  TOMONTH NUMBER(5),
                  IMPORTO NUMBER(18,4) ); 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('01',1,10,3250); 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('01',11,24,5625);
```

What I want to get is something like this: Yearly payment = 43750 ---> 10 months * 3250 + 2 months 5625

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: CREATE TABLE T1
(
  CODCTR     VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  FROMMONTH  NUMBER(5),
  TOMONTH    NUMBER(5),
  IMPORTO    NUMBER(18,4)
);


INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('01',1,10,3250);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('01',11,24,5625);

What i want to get is something like this:
Yearly payment = 43750 ---> 10 months * 3250 + 2 months 5625

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it with additional information. Code and sample data are particularly hard to read in comments due to the lack of layout options  and poor formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with a lists of months:

```
CREATE TABLE M1 (CURMONTH NUMBER(5));
INSERT INTO M1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO M1 VALUES (2);
...
INSERT INTO M1 VALUES (12);
```

then you can join it to your table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM M1
  JOIN T1 ON M1.curmonth BETWEEN t1.frommonth AND t1.tomonth;
```

This join has the payment due in curmonth. Once you have that, you can easily `SUM` the payments:

```
SELECT SUM(importo)
  FROM M1
  JOIN T1 ON M1.curmonth BETWEEN t1.frommonth AND t1.tomonth;
```

You can even create the table with the interesting months on the fly:

```
WITH m1 AS (SELECT LEVEL as curmonths FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
SELECT SUM(importo) 
  FROM t1 JOIN m1 ON m1.curmonths BETWEEN t1.frommonth AND t1.tomonth;
```